# Avoid rebuilding of unselected and restored cmake subdirectories

Tags: cmake

I have a CMake project with multiple targets which are added via `add_subdirectory`, and `add_subdirectory` calls are guarded by options. Using `Ninja` as build runner.

Now when I turn some specific option off and reconfigure, all object files for the now missing subdirectory are apparently invalidated. When I turn the option back on, `add_subdirectory` is run again but it wants to **recompile everything from scratch**.

Obviously `ccache` helps here a lot because the input and output are perfectly identical. But copying objects around is still much slower than not copying anything at all, and the linker runtime comes on top.

Is there any way to tell cmake: if subdirectory is gone, please consider this temporarily and keep the files and their information valid, just not use them?

Comment: Don't guard add_subdirectory. Add them every time. Just don't build them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if subdirectory is gone, please consider this temporarily and keep the files and their information valid, just not use them?

Exactly, so do not use them. Do not modify `add_subdirectory`, change the dependency of projects not to depend on the targets exported by subdirectory.

```
add_subdirectory(A EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
if(option)
   target_link_libraries(your_super_target A)
endif()
```

Comment: Didn't realize that add_subdirectory has that option. In my case target_link_libraries was not needed since the subprojects are building executables, wich get into ALL automatically. Had it been different then I would need to track their targets somehow, either with target_link_libraries as suggested here or with add_dependencies. Anyway, the idea is clear, thanks.